# I have a question about react-router v4, i don't understand it

Tags: routes, react-router

When I read react-router (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route[enter link description here][1])

it's:
The “react-empty” comments are just implementation details of React’s null rendering. But for our purposes, it is instructive. A Route is always technically “rendered” even though its rendering null. When the 's path matches the current URL, it renders its children (your component).

but i don't understand this, can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EVery time your page loads it loads all the routes, not just the one you are on.  However, every other route is rendered null until clicked.  Once clicked, the previous Component you were on will be rendered null.  Null means nothing is going to be returned, and the children in this case refers to the actual Component that is going to be rendered upon clicking the route.

Comment: please mark as answered if you feel this answers your question.  This is for future on lookers.